# jQuery ajax call not sending anything on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile-safari

We have a web application that sends data to a HTTPS server using the following code:

```
$.ajax(this.getConfig().serverUrl, {
            data: xml,
            dataType: "xml",
            method: "POST",
            timeout: 20000
        })
        .done(_onGameResponseLoaded)
        .fail(_onGameRequestError);
```

This has been working on desktop browsers and Android, but we've hit issues on iOS 8/9 Safari where we don't see the request succeed, and it times out. We've connected the device to Fiddler to see what is coming from it, and it doesn't look like the request is being sent. This only seems to be the case on iOS. I've seen some things about there being a caching bug introduced in iOS 6, but nothing more recent.

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: None, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the error in `Network tab` ?

Comment: No error message, status, size, duration, etc are all "-” and it's highlighted in red. Seems to just be timing out.

Comment: Seems like more of a server side issue.. Serious debugging is needed...Good Luck...

Comment: Thanks, think I may need it. Not sure it's a server issue, can't see why it'd only be happening on iOS if so. Wondering if it's a race condition somewhere else in the client. Either way, think it's going to be _fun_ to debug.